# Why is my RSA encryption code work for small bit sizes but, not larger ones?

Tags: java, encryption, rsa

I don't code much but, when I'm trying to implement RSA encryption in JAVA my encryption and decryption work for smaller size primes but, when I try to do it for 1536 bit size prime numbers the decryption stops working. I've gone through it but, I don't see what the problem is.

I've already tried to see at what point the bit length starts to be an issue and it seems to be when I set it to 50 is when stops working. I also tend to get an error were my mod inverse method throws an error about e.modinv(lambda)
not being possible. I tried fixing this by adding the do loop but, it seems like this didn't fix the issue.

```
public BigInteger Random_Prime()
{
    SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
    byte [] randomize = new byte [192];
    random.nextBytes(randomize);
    BigInteger big = new BigInteger(randomize);
    return big.probablePrime(1536,random);
}
public BigInteger lcm(BigInteger p, BigInteger q)
{
    long p1 = p.longValue()-1;
    long q1 = q.longValue()-1;
    BigInteger test1 = p.valueOf(p1);
    BigInteger test2 = p.valueOf(q1);
    return test1.multiply(test2).divide(test1.gcd(test2));
```

do {

```
        p = obj1.Random_Prime();
        q = obj1.Random_Prime();
        lambda = obj1.lcm(p, q);
    }
    while(lambda.gcd(e).compareTo(ONE)!=0);
    BigInteger n = p.multiply(q);
    BigInteger m = new BigInteger("75");
    BigInteger d = e.modInverse(lambda);
    BigInteger c = obj1.Encrypt(n,e,m);
```

I expect 75 to come back as 75 after going through encryption and decryption.

Comment: Did you get the JCE extension?

Comment: I don't really do much coding and don't know what that is.

Comment: [Strong encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Export_of_cryptography_from_the_United_States) is *regulated*.

Comment: This is an assignment for class

Comment: @ElliottFrisch: Oracle Java stopped enforcing the old ITAR-based policy by default in 2017 (OpenJDK never did in the first place), and even before that it only applied to _symmetric_ algorithms (mostly AES) in the JCE providers, not to RSA and certainly not to code you write yourself.

Answer (score 4):

**Your `lcm()` is wrong.**

Java `long` is only 64 bits including sign, and cannot represent numbers greater than 2^63. (Or equal, but a large prime is never equal to a power of 2.) Thus your `lcm` computation should work for p,q up to 63 bits, and does for me, but produce totally wrong and useless results for anything larger. Instead use `{p,q}.subtract(BigInteger.ONE)` for the numbers you multiply-and-divide-by-gcd.

Also, `BigInteger.probablePrime(int,Random)` is a `static` (aka classwide) method; you do not need to call it using any instance, much less one with a random value you wasted time computing because it is ignored. For that matter `BigInteger.valueOf(long)` is also `static` and ignores any instance used to call it. If you are using any kind of Java development environment more advanced than simply typing `javac` to a shell or COMMAND, it should (at least optionally) give you a warning about using an instance to call a static method.

Finally, if you aren't aware, using the RSA primitives m^e mod n and c^d mod n directly to encrypt/decrypt data, especially small data, is not secure. You *must* use a sufficiently large and random padding scheme for this to be secure at all; see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_%28cryptosystem%29) for a short explanation, and if you want more search on https://crypto.stackexchange.com and maybe https://security.stackexchange.com where this has been asked about and answered *many* times. And if you decrypt (which you didn't show) simply by doing `c.modPow(d,n)` that is both inefficient (see wikipedia about CRT) and insecure (see wikipedia about timing attacks, and again crypto.SX and security.SX). And using RSA directly for data is very limiting and inefficient, so in practice people use *hybrid* encryption -- use a symmetric algorithm (nowadays usually AES) to encrypt the data under a nonce key, and encrypt that nonce key using RSA -- or perhaps better *derive* it using RSA-KEM (again see wikipedia crypto.SX security.SX).

**If you actually want security** and not just to play about, **use the crypto from the Java library** which has been implemented correctly (and reviewed) by competent people, unlike your code.